# Creating a new dictionary from lists of tuples and characters

Tags: dictionary, tuples

I have example two lists:

```
list1=[(0,1), (0,2), (1,3),...]

list 2: ["louis", "Montgomery", ...]
```

How can I create a dictionary like this:

```
{(0,1) : "louis", (0,2) : 'Montgomery", ...}
```

Comment: Which programming environment do you use? Please elaborate on that to enable answers.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dict(zip(list1,list2))
```